# JAXB Unmarshalling Fails

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

Getting following error while unmarshalling a response String(in xml format). Initially it was complaining about the  and ,so I removed the soap part from the response.Now it comes up with this error.

Classes are created from provided WSDL using JAXB 2

```
**javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com", local:"calculateDocumentResponse"). Expected elements are (none)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:662)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:258)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:253)**
```

Here is my response string (part of it)

```
**<calculateDocumentResponse xmlns="http://ws.taxwareenterprise.com">
            <txDocRslt>
                <jurSumRslts>
                    <jurSumRslt>
                        <xmptAmt>5.0</xmptAmt>
                        <txableAmt>15.0</txableAmt>
                        <txAmt>0.04</txAmt>
                        <txJurUID>...**
```

Here goes my xsd for "CalculationResponse"(part of it)

```
<xs:complexType name="CalculationResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="txDocRslt" type="tns:TxDocRslt"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

and this is my code for unmarshalling:

```
**final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(CalculationResponse.class);
            final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            response = processResponse(response);//for removing soap headers
            responseObj = (CalculationResponse) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(response));//Fails here...
            final TxDocRslt txDocRslt = responseObj.getTxDocRslt();**
```